# Podio API Key after leaving workspace

Tags: podio

I am collaborating with another person on Podio to integrate various external applications with an information management system we have created on Podio.

I need to clarify my understanding regarding the generation of API Keys.  Specifically, API Keys are generated from a User's Account Settings.  If I generate the API Keys for an integration and I am later removed from that Workspace, does this terminate the connection with the App in Podio?

I know, simple question and the obvious answer is yes, it would terminate the connection, but I would like to know if anyone has direct experience with this and can confirm my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to use the Podio API Keys. The Client-ID and Client-Secret *alone* do not give you access to apps or workspaces. The Client-ID and Client-Secret are merely identifying you as a 'Developer', who has been granted the privilege to use Podio API.  Again, this data *alone* does not grant your user access ANY workspace nor app.

Let's review how Podio API authentication works in more details:
Main documentation page: https://developers.podio.com/authentication

Example in Ruby:

```
Podio.setup(
  :api_key    => 'USER_0_CLIENT_ID',
  :api_secret => 'USER_0_CLIENT_SECRET'
)
begin
  Podio.client.authenticate_with_credentials('USER_1', 'PASSWD')
  # got access to ALL info that USER_1 can access, but not USER_0

  Podio.client.authenticate_with_credentials('USER_2', 'PASSWD')
  # got access to ALL info that USER_2 can access (but won't be able to access any info from USER_1 nor USER_0)

  Podio.client.authenticate_with_app('APP_1_ID', 'APP_1_TOKEN')
  # get access to APP_1 items (and nothing else), and it doesn't matter if USER_0 has access to APP_1 or not (nor USER_1, nor USER_2)

  Podio.client.authenticate_with_app('APP_2_ID', 'APP_2_TOKEN')
  # get access to APP_2 items (and nothing else), and it doesn't matter if USER_0 has access to APP_2 or not

rescue Podio::PodioError => ex
  # Something went wrong
end
```

Therefore, you need a valid Client-ID/Client-Secret *in addition to* valid authentication credentials to actually gain access to any information inside Podio. The authentication credentials could be in the form of another's user login/password, an app_id/app_token, or an access_token that is generated by Podio when user logged in via the server-side flow or client-side flow.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  #2 is applicable to what I am referring to, but if the Client ID and Client Secret Key are part of an API connection from a user that no longer has access to a workspace, how can they continue to have access?

Comment: I've re-structured answer to make it clear that Client ID and Client Secret doesn't give any access, but only full combination of ClientID/Secret with username/password or app_id/token or access_token can give access to Podio apps and items.